# TemplateDoesNotExist in project folder django 1.8

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-1.8

I have structured my application Django (Django 1.8) as shown below.
When I try template in app1 or app2 extends base.html in base.html of my application, I get this error.

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
base.html
Error during template rendering

In template /myProject/project_folder/app1/templates/app1/base.html, error at line 1
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

Here is structure of my project

```
/projekt_folder
    template
        base.html
    /app1
        /template
            base.html <-- {% extends "base.html" %}
    /app2
        /template
            base.html <-- {% extends "base.html" %}
```

Comment: Does {% extends "template/base.html" %} work?

Comment: What is your TEMPLATES setting?

Comment: Please show your settings file. Or perhaps [dpaste](http://dpaste.com) it.

Comment: Here is my settings.py: http://dpaste.com/1W06XKR

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to tell Django what is the additional location of your template folder (`projekt_folder/template`) which is not under installed apps, add following lines at top of your settings file:

```
import os

PACKAGE_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Then set `DIRS` in `TEMPLATES` setting var:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, 'template')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Maddeningly, the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` tuple is silently ignored once you have a `TEMPLATES` list.

Answer (score 0):

Django 3.1.5:
You need to tell Django template engine where to look for your base.html template by adding it's path in the DIRS like this :

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
   
    # Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
    # BASE_DIR in your case is '/projekt_folder'
    'DIRS': [
        BASE_DIR / 'template'
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},]
```